Why are Old Testament books like Esther and Songs of Solomon considered scripture?
I understand the typical process of canonization especially for the New Testament (written by an apostle, eyewitness or someone who knew an eye witness). But I’m less clear on the criteria for Old Testament books and I don’t understand particularly why Esther and Songs of Solomon are considered the God breathed inspired word of God. Other Old Testament books are quoted by Jesus and other New Testament people but the book of Esther doesn’t even mention God once. I really like the books but I’m wondering why they’re considered scripture (I’m not saying they shouldn’t be I just want to know why they were historically).

This has been asked on Christianity.SE. The TL;DR is that they're in the Jewish canon. Regarding Esther: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/103198/why-was-esther-included-in-the-canon and https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/6938/why-isnt-god-mentioned-in-esther. Song of Solomon: https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/11295/why-is-the-song-of-solomon-in-bible

Considered scripture by who?

Christianity utilizes the Jewish canon and then adds their canon on top of it (though some differ; roman catholic, ethiopian, protestant, etc).
As such, it's important to note what the actual criteria for the tanakh inclusion was (which differs slightly from the NT) and their level of 'scripture'.

Torah: The first five books (also called Pentateuch) were included because they were given directly by G-d to Moses and are the foundational text to which ALL writings and scripture must be tested against. This is the highest level of scripture.
Nevi'im: These books were attributed to the prophets or a scribe of a prophet (also known as 'the prophets'). This is the second highest level of scripture.
Ketuvim: Also known as 'writings' were not necessarily written by prophets, but were understood to be divinely inspired. This is the third highest level of scripture.

Critera:

Accuracy & Authority: The text had to be aligned with the established Jewish belief according to the Pharisaic understanding during the 2nd temple period. Books that fell outside of the known tradition or not rooted in historical reality were not accepted. For this reason, Joshua, Judges, Samuel, and Kings were included because they aligned with the existing narrative taught by the rabbis (a pharisaic title) in the synagogues (a pharisaic institution) and passed on to their disciples.
Consistency with Torah Values & Teachings: A book had to be consistent with the core values and theology presented in the Torah. If a text was seen as undermining core Torah principles, it was excluded from the canon. This meant that books had to reflect proper moral, legal, and theological views in accordance with the rest of the canon.
Language & Authorship: The canon only included books written in Hebrew or, in some cases, contain some Aramaic (like parts of Daniel and Ezra). Texts that originated in Greek or other languages, like those in the later Apocrypha, were not accepted into the canon because they were seen as foreign and less authoritative. If a text was written in Greek, it would be extremely problematic as the greek is difficult to align with Hebrew. As a great example of this, at the conclusion of writing the LXX (Greek version of Torah) by the 70 elders, the authors said it was worse than the day of the golden calf (Tractate Seforim) because it was a departure from the Hebraic, stripped it from its deeper meaning and connections, and could cause someone to believe in false theology.

Now, books like Ezekiel, Esther, Ecclesiastes, and Song of Songs (of the canon) were debated (along with Sirach - noncanonical), due to questions about their content. But they were accepted because of the traditional interpretations and Pharisaic recognition of the deeper meaning, which was upheld through the exegetical method of PaRDeS. Books that did not uphold PaRDeS and failed to meet this criteria included Tobit, Judith, the Maccabees books, 2 Esdras, and Wisdom of Solomon. They failed to pass the test of PaRDeS, Pharisaic tradition, or being written in a foreign language.
The Tanakh composes of the following books:
Torah
Genesis
Exodus
Leviticus
Numbers
Deuteronomy
Prophets
Joshua
Judges
Samuel
Kings
Isaiah
Jeremiah
Ezekiel
The Twelve (Minor prophets in the OT)
Writings
Psalms
Proverbs
Job
Song of Songs
Ruth
Lamentations
Ecclesiastes
Esther
Daniel
Ezra-Nehemiah
Chronicles
However, this isn't the only thing that is considered 'divine' in rabbinic Judaism. There is also the "oral torah" or mishnah which contains the interpretation of the law (Torah) and is slightly more flexible. From there, you also have the Shulchan Aruch which is the codified Jewish law, and then minhag (customs) of each community which are legally binding as it states:

"You shall appoint judges and officers for your tribes, in all your towns that the Lord your God is giving you, and they shall judge the people with righteous judgment." Deuteronomy 16:18


"If a case is too difficult for you to judge—between blood and blood, between plea and plea, and between stroke and stroke, matters of controversy in your gates—then you shall arise and go up to the place which the Lord your God shall choose. You shall come to the priests, the Levites, and to the judge who will be in those days, and you shall inquire, and they shall declare to you the sentence of judgment." Deuteronomy 17:8-13

So there is a "written canon" but it is not the totality of authority.

This is such a well thought out and written answer. Thank you for taking the time out to answer my question so thoroughly God bless!

Bottom line, they are prophetic of Messiah. Nothing else to really say. If books were consistent with the revelation of Messiah, and authorship was genuine, it was accepted. Usually the books in the OT, which you are talking about??? Were canonized before Jesus' time.
Also, the Jewish OT (Tanach/ Tanakh) has some extra books that ours doesn't have like Maccabees for example. So there are different canons that are used. In Jesus' day, they had the original Septuagint that was read, as well as the Aramaic scrolls.
Books that didn't make it into the canon were books that went against the overall theme of scripture and ventured into unknown territory, or were know forgeries or pseudapigraphas.
In the case of 1 Maccabees it was denied canonization due to a small section where the Jews who were trying to re-establish the temple area that was destroyed hundreds of years earlier by the Babylonians, were praying to the dead. Since this is considered by Christians to be necromancy and divination, the book was rejected by the counsel. The Catholic Apocrypha and the Tanach still use 1 Maccabees and others.
